# How to make a default page in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

[image]

Why I have index.android.js as default. How I can make a home.js as default?

Answer (score 0):

> When your platform-specific code is more complex, you should consider splitting the code out into separate files. React Native will detect when a file has a `.ios.` or `.android.` extension and load the relevant platform file when required from other components.

see: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/platform-specific-code.html#platform-specific-extensions

so if you add `.android.js` or `.ios.js` to your extension RN will pick one of them based on the platform. If you want the same component for both platform just don't add platform specific extension and use just `foo.js`

Answer (score 0):

I think what you asked for can be done this way:

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import Home from './path/to/home';
AppRegistry.registerComponent('SBlank', () => Home);
```

By doing this in both your `index.android.js` and `index.ios.js` you redirect your app to Home.js file.

**Bonus:** In addition to knowbody's answer, you can use `Platform` object to change how your code works on different platforms. For example:

```
render() {
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
        return this.renderAndroid();
    }
    return this.renderIOS();
}
```

where you import Platform by adding

```
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
```